# Receiving Error Message when using command over()

Tags: r, shapefile, centroid, rgeo-shapefile

I have two shape files, `shp1` and `shp2`. After calculating the centroid of the former, I'd like to see where the centroid lies in the latter.

My setup does:

```
shp1@data$centroid <- gCentroid(shp1, byid = TRUE)
foo <- over(shp1$centroid, shp2)
```

Upon executing the second line, I receive the following error message:

```
Error in xj[i] : NAs not permitted in row index
```

Any idea what I should be looking for to avoid this error? (note: `grep("NA", row.names(shp1))` returns `integer(0)`, also for the other shape file.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out why this error occurs:

In addition to `shp1@data$centroid <- gCentroid(shp1, byid = TRUE)`, I also did `shp2@data$centroid <- gCentroid(shp2, byid = TRUE)` before calling `foo <- over(shp1$centroid, shp2)`, which apparently caused the error.